# Apache Camel & Springboot - 404 status - Response body blank when customer tries to reach an invalid/undefined endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I am trying to have a custom json response body indicate to the customer that they tried to reach an invalid route. When they are missing a parameter in their request for ex. localhost:8080/hello//is/my/path versus the correct path localhost:8080/hello/this/is/my/path camel gives 404 status but the response is blank. I can't seem to add a custom response as camel doesn't even read my code. It just gives 404 status without even an exception. Please help.

I tried adding global exception handlers as well as default routes but none of this code is even read.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

ExceptionHandler Class

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ApiExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler({NoHandlerFoundException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<ApiErrorResponse> handleNoHandlerFoundException(
            NoHandlerFoundException ex, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        ApiErrorResponse apiErrorResponse = new ApiErrorResponse(404, "Resource not found");
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(apiErrorResponse);
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
```

And add
@EnableWebMvc to main application class

[Source](https://bootcamptoprod.com/customizing-404-response-springboot/)

Comment: What would ApiErrorResponse be? I don't have that

Comment: it just basically response u are returning to client side, u can change that with your own response body @yumyum321